# Swagger not working in Rails Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, swagger, rails-api

gem 'swagger-docs'

rake swagger:docs

rails server

My controller is in app/controller/API/user_controller.rb

```
    module Api
    class UserController < ApplicationController

    swagger_controller :users, "Users"
    swagger_api :create do
        summary "Creates a new User"
        param :form, :name, :string, :required, "Name"
        response :unauthorized
        response :not_acceptable
    end

    def create
            render json: {message: "success"},status: 401
    end

end
```

end

But when I enter

```
http://localhost:3000/api-docs.json
```

It can't work properly. It cant show proper layout.Rather than that it gives json code of that.

```
{
"apiVersion": "1.0",
"swaggerVersion": "1.2",
"basePath": "/",
"apis": [
 {
   "path": "api/user.{format}",
  "description": "Users"
 }
]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning JSON is the default behaviour of `swagger-docs`. If you want to see the layout from this [screenshot](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs-sample/blob/master/swagger-docs-screenshot-1.png) you need to use `swagger-ui` as well. See the example here https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs-sample/tree/c33e1e788b8ef5a71c86610fffbb145b243a725b/public/api

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is it a gem or either js file, Kindly just clear only this. Thanks :)

Comment: it's javascript. you also gonna need to include css, images and additional js libraries.